# Is "Are you (or Have you been) informed?" a natural expression even when used without any context or clues?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

The other day, my colleague asked me to proofread a checklist with a check item below.

*Have you been informed by the Ministry of Economy, Trade, and Industry?  Yes or No*

It was an independent check item with no context given nor connection with any of the previous or the following check items, so I couldn't understand what the question was all about.

My quick Google search for the phrase returned many pages including the short question sentence, but they all seem to come with some sort of context.

Is "Are you (or Have you been) informed?" natural English even without any context or clues regarding what information is being discussed?

Comment: A native English speaker would ask 'informed of _what_?'. The sentence would be seen as incomplete.

Comment: _Have you been informed...?_ is perfectly natural, but, as Michael says, only if we know _of what._ _Are you informed_ doesn't work in this sense

Comment: I think probably this is a form of "translation error", and what the checklist item *should* be asking is something more like *Have you **registered with** the ministry* (as in *Have you **informed** the ministry [of your status as a trader, or whatever]?*

Comment: Both **Are you informed** and **Have you been informed** are grammatically correct and natural, but they mean somewhat different things.  "Are you informed" = "Do you know"  "Have you been informed" = "Has someone told you".  So if someone *has informed* you, you *are informed* now, but they're not quite interchangeable.

Comment: In English, no-one says, "Have you been informed?" without context, because the sentence is missing critical information that the hearer needs. It isn't an idiom.